how to draw a Turbojet engine picture

This is my first time using tikz but I'm afraid I didn't really get how to properly use it (I keep making a mess getting errors everywhere), so I was hoping you guys could help me drawing this scheme with tikz.

Welcome! We'd be happy to help with the errors if you share a minimal bit of code we can compile to reproduce them, but (1) this is not a do-it-for-me style site. (There are people you can hire, but not here.) If you're extraordinarily lucky, somebody will take a fancy to your goal and answer before the question gets closed, but the odds are not in your favour. Also, (2) questions shouldn't rely on external links. I see no image in your question. I'm extremely wary of following links to unknown sites posted by strangers. (Exception to (1): if you need a duck, somebody will do it for you.)

Assuming you can do the content of the nodes (which I certainly couldn't), you can do most of this using stuff covered in the tutorial in the TikZ manual. The bits you'd need are nodes for the text, numbers and boxes and paths for the lines. Or just draw it in your favourite GUI programme if you don't want to bother with it, then use \includegraphics. (I'm assuming the current version isn't adequate or you could just include that.)

You can try TikzEdt (www.tikzedt.org). It helps to draw simple Tikz diagrams quickly using WYSIWYG tools.

For example like this:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[minimum size=5em] (a) {进气道};
\node[draw, minimum size=5em, right=of a] (b) {压气机};
\node[draw, minimum size=5em, right=of b] (c) {燃烧室};
\node[draw, minimum size=5em, right=of c] (d) {涡轮};
\node[minimum size=5em, right=of d] (e) {尾喷管};

\draw (b.south) -- +(0,-0.5) -| (d.south);
\draw[dashed] 
    ([yshift=-0.5cm]b.south) -- +(-4.5,0)
    ([yshift=-0.5cm]d.south) -- +(4.5,0);

\draw 
    ([shift={(-0.5,-0.75)}]a.north west) -- +(0,1.75)
        coordinate (ax)
        node[anchor=north east] {\strut 0}
    ([shift={(0.5,-0.5)}]e.south east) -- ([shift={(0.5,1)}]e.north east)
        coordinate (fx)
        node[anchor=north east] {\strut 8}
        node[anchor=north west] {\strut (9)};

\foreach \n [count=\i from 2] in {b,c,d,e} {
    \draw 
        ([shift={(-0.5,-0.25)}]\n.north west) -- +(0,1.25)
            coordinate (\n x)
            node[anchor=north east] {\strut \i};
}

\draw 
    ([yshift=-3em]ax) to[out=30, in=180] 
    ([yshift=-1.5em]bx) --
    ([yshift=-1.5em]ex) to[out=0, in=150] 
    ([yshift=-3em]fx);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



What's going on here? First, I draw the nodes. They should all have the shape of a square and the three nodes in the middle should have a border. I achieve this by using \node[minimum size=5em] {...}; where the option minimum size sets a height and width to the node making it a square. I also use the positioning library to place the nodes relative to each other. Finally, I name then a, b, ... e for later reference.
I then draw the lines below the nodes: One solid line that starts from b.south (which is the middle of the lower border of node b), goes down a bit, then to the right and up again to d.south. I make use of the -| operator that draws a rectangular line between two coordinates (horizontally first, then vertically). I also add the dashed parts of the line, using the yshift option to shift down the starting coordinate.
Now, I draw the lines above the nodes, first just the vertical lines with the numbers. I start with the outermost lines, now using the shift option to shift the starting coordinates horizontally and vertically. Then, I use a \foreach loop to add the other lines. Here, I make use of a counter to add the numbers.
Finally, I draw the curvy line, making use of some coordinates I placed to the drawing beforehand. I use the to[out=..., in=...] syntax to draw the curves at the start and end of the path.
